# function to call shell script with arguments

Tags: vimscript, external-command

I am making my own function to call a bash script that compiles and runs my program.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    !_compile a:game a:major a:minor
endfunction
```

The only issue is it seems to parse `a:game` instead of the value.

How would I get `a:game`, `a:major`, `a:minor` to parse their value to the function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Using `:execute`

All command arguments in Vim are interpreted literally unless designed to be evaluated. To build a command dynamically, you can use [`:execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute). Each argument to `:execute` is evaluated, and they are all joined by a space to produce the final command.

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    execute '!_compile' a:game a:major a:minor
endfunction
```

### Incorporating `shellescape()`

It's a good idea to escape arguments being passed to the shell using [`shellescape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29). It takes a string and escapes it for use in a shell command.

```
function Compile_and_run(game, major, minor)
    execute '!_compile' shellescape(a:game) shellescape(a:major) shellescape(a:minor)
endfunction
```

Comment: Why do I need `''` for `!_compile` other than other arguments?

Comment: `:execute`'s arguments are VimScript expressions that should evaluate to strings. If you pass multiple arguments, they will be joined with spaces. Since the first argument is just a literal string, we enclose it in quotes.